# Wi-Fi not showing up after kernel upgrade from 3.10 to 3.16 in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, kernel, lenovo-laptop

I upgraded the kernel in Ubuntu 14.04 from 3.10 to 3.16. My system is a Lenovo G510 59398431. After that the option “enable wifi” in the drop-down of wireless icon on the desktop is not there. Even in the network section in system settings the wireless section is not showing up.

Comment: How to know what wi-fi card is installed?

Comment: I am using Lenovo G510 59398431.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this is a kernel level Wi-Fi driver related issue. You say your machine is a Lenovo G510 59398431, correct? Doing [a search for the Lenovo G510 documentation](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-g-series-laptops/lenovo-g510-notebook) on Lenovo’s official site shows the following regulatory notice PDF document:

- [Lenovo Regulatory Notice - Lenovo G400, G500, G405, G505, G410, G510](http://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/lenovo_g400g500g405g505g410g510_rn.pdf)

And looking into that is a list of factory preinstalled Wireless LAN/WiMAX modules; bolded items are my quick research on what those model numbers mean in English:

- FCC ID: PD9135BNHU (Model: 135BNHMW, **Intel Centrino 135**)
- FCC ID: QDS-BRCM1050I (Model: BCM94313HMG2L, **Dell Dw1501 PCI-E Wireless Wlan Card Broadcom 4313**)
- FCC ID: QDS-BRCM1063 (Model: BCM943142HM, **Broadcom**)
- FCC ID: PPD-AR5B125 (Model: AR5B125, **Atheros**)
- FCC ID: PPD-AR5B225 (Model: AR5B225, **Atheros**)
- FCC ID: PPD-QCWB335 (Model: QCWB335, **Qualcomm Atheros**)

Which means any one of those is installed on your Lenovo G510. If there is an easy way for you to figure out which one is installed, then a path to a solution will present itself.

For example, in this thread a user with a MacBook Air running Ubuntu 14.04 [the solution was to install the Broadcom kernel STA drivers](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2231441&page=2&p=13062151#post13062151). Details on what `bcmwl-kernel-source` contains [can be found here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/bcmwl-kernel-source).

Comment: The following command gives me this results:
`lspci -nn | grep -e 0200 -e 0280`

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8172 Fast Ethernet [1969:10a0] (rev 10)
Is this related to what you mentioned?